# How do I add a plugin to a Static placeholder in Django CMS

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm begining to use Static Placeholders in Django-CMS and I want to bootstrap a pace and create a "footer" static placeholder. Something like:

```
static_placeholder = StaticPlaceholder(
    name=static_placeholder_code,
    code=static_placeholder_code,
    creation_method=StaticPlaceholder.CREATION_BY_CODE
)
static_placeholder.save()
```

I tried adding a TextPlugin with the api.add_plugin but got an error

```
add_plugin(
    placeholder=static_placeholder,
    plugin_type='TextPlugin',
    language='en',
)
```

Since static_placeholder is not an instance of Placeholder add_plugin does not work.
in the add_plugin function: assert isinstance(placeholder, Placeholder)

What would be the best way to add a TextPlugin to this static placeholder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StaticPlaceholder` is a model that has two foreign key relationships to the `Placeholder` model, one is called `draft`, the other is called `public`. Both will give you a `Placeholder` instance.

You could just use:

```
add_plugin(
    placeholder=static_placeholder.draft,
    plugin_type='TextPlugin',
    language='en',
)
```

and it will work, but keep in mind that you should always use `draft` as the example above, this is because when you publish, all plugins from `draft` will be copied over to the `public` placeholder.

Last not sure on the specifics of your app, but should point out that when the staticplaceholder is rendered in a template, it's not necessary to create it before hand. You can just do:

```
{% load cms_tags %}

{% static_placeholder 'footer' %}
```

This will then get or create the `footer` static placeholder.

Comment: I created the placeholders by code but thanks for clarifying! An extra thumbs up for explaining the publishing process, probably saved me a whole bunch of hours!